# Generate Juju bundle from juju status

Tags: juju

I deployed some charms in my model, and added some relations between those charms. Now I would like to set up my environment in another model. Is there a possibility to create a `bundle.yaml` from my current setup? So the next time I would like to do the exact same thing, I can just deploy the bundle that will setup exactly the same model as my first model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Juju CLI

`juju export-bundle`

#### Juju GUI

The Juju Gui has a solution for this. Next to your modelname in de GUI there is an import and export button.

[image: juju gui]

The Export button will generate a yaml file which will represent your current model. This yaml can be used in the Juju GUI to import in to a new model or can be used in the Juju-CLI as well.